# AWS Elastic Beanstalk response delay isse

Tags: java, jsp, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have AWS Elastic Beanstalk deployed jsp web application

Whenever I am clicking for Log of my application from console at that time immediately server gets restarted automatically. This problem I faced before month ago but after some days it was resolved automatically.

Even from 3 days response time of your server so much increased. The app which is running on localhost is giving response in 5-6 secs. On AWS same responce getting in 20-22 sec.

Comment: Does your app has this long response time even for simple pages which doesn't touch any external resources like DB, web services?

Comment: I solved this problem. Issue is from AWS side. It happens when logs fetches from AWS.

Comment: I am using loggly now.! AWS logs forwarding using API to loggly !